How to burn LP on Solana with CLI?
I am a new dev on Solana, I just added liquidity to my token and want to know how or where to burn the lp tokens. Does Solana have a burn mechanism? Is there a burn or dead address like Ethereum that I can just transfer the lp tokens to?

You can burn tokens using the burn instruction. Here's a sample CLI command to do it:
spl-token burn <TOKEN_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> <TOKEN_AMOUNT>

